# How to add custom data to cart for a specific product which I have shown on a page programmatically and with a separate anchor adding it to cart?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

My scenario is I have a product which I'm showing on my home page with my shortcode not with woo commerce shortcode. What I want is I need to show a text box under that and once user fills that and click on my custom add to cart button that data should be shown in my cart. I don't want to use product single page for that my requirement is to do it on home page.

Site link: https://handyva.com/larry/

```php
    function iconic_output_engraving_field() {
        global $product;

        if ( $product->get_id() !== 95 ) {
            return;
        }

        ?>
        <div class="iconic-engraving-field">
            <label for="iconic-engraving"><?php _e( 'Engraving (10 characters)', 'iconic' ); ?></label>
            <input type="text" id="iconic-engraving" name="iconic-engraving" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Enter engraving text', 'iconic' ); ?>" maxlength="10">
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'iconic_output_engraving_field', 10 );




    function iconic_add_engraving_text_to_cart_item( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {
        $engraving_text = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'iconic-engraving' );

        if ( empty( $engraving_text ) ) {
            return $cart_item_data;
        }

        $cart_item_data['iconic-engraving'] = $engraving_text;

        return $cart_item_data;
    }

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'iconic_add_engraving_text_to_cart_item', 10, 3 );

    function iconic_display_engraving_text_cart( $item_data, $cart_item ) {
        if ( empty( $cart_item['iconic-engraving'] ) ) {
            return $item_data;
        }

        $item_data[] = array(
            'key'     => __( 'Engraving', 'iconic' ),
            'value'   => wc_clean( $cart_item['iconic-engraving'] ),
            'display' => '',
        );
        return $item_data;
    }

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'iconic_display_engraving_text_cart', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Please look at my comment to get better understanding of my question:

My scenario is I have a product which I'm showing on my home page with my shortcode not with woo commerce shortcode. What I want is I need to show a text box under that and once user fills that and click on my custom add to cart button that data should be shown in my cart. I don't want to use product single page for that my requirement is to do it on home page.

Site link: https://handyva.com/larry/

Comment: have you got the text in $engraving_text , that you have entered in textbox

Comment: Yes I got that from the single product page but its not working from the main page because the filter that code using is before add to cart its working fine on single product page.

Comment: Have you check, all the hook(woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button & woocommerce_add_cart_item_data) which has been placed in you custom shortcode? - @Syed Furqan Ali